# how would I sort an array of hashes by one value and then sort it again after that?

Tags: ruby

I have a massive array of hashes that I need to order by the numerical value of `:job_num` after its sorted by `:job_num` I need to sort it by `:date`

```
array = [
  {job_num: 1236, date: Date.parse('2016/10/19')},
  {job_num: 1234, date: Date.parse('2016/10/17')},
  {job_num: 1236, date: Date.parse('2016/10/20')},
  {job_num: 1233, date: Date.parse('2016/10/18')}
]
# => [{:job_num=>1236, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-19 ((2457681j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1234, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-17 ((2457679j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1236, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-20 ((2457682j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1233, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-18 ((2457680j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]
```

I need to first sort my array by `:job_num`

```
array.sort! { |x,y| x[:job_num] <=> y[:job_num] }
# => [{:job_num=>1233, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-18 ((2457680j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1234, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-17 ((2457679j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1236, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-20 ((2457682j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}, {:job_num=>1236, :date=>#<Date: 2016-10-19 ((2457681j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]
```

I then need it to sort by date after sorting by the job number, it should end up that the array looks like this if all goes well:

```
array = [
  {job_num: 1233, date: '2016/10/18'},
  {job_num: 1234, date: '2016/10/17'},
  {job_num: 1236, date: '2016/10/19'},
  {job_num: 1236, date: '2016/10/20'}
]
```

(I left off the date parse in the final array since its only an example and irrelevant to the logic)

Comment: Can you post some code of your attempts at doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
array.sort_by! { |item| [item[:job_num], item[:date]] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the Ruby enum sort_by method:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'

puts "Sorting an array"
array = [
    {job_num: 1236, date: Date.parse('2016/10/19')},
    {job_num: 1234, date: Date.parse('2016/10/17')},
    {job_num: 1236, date: Date.parse('2016/10/20')},
    {job_num: 1233, date: Date.parse('2016/10/18')},
]

puts array

array.sort_by! { |x| [ x[:job_num], x[:date] ] } 

puts
puts array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.sort! { |x,y| 
  by_job_num = x[:job_num] <=> y[:job_num]
  by_job_num.zero? ? x[:date] <=> y[:date] : by_job_num
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)